# solr SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(),&#8203; indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a Solr cloud (version 7.4) with 2 nodes (each one has 10Gb SSD hard and 256Gb memory and 50Gb heap) and 10 collections.
Today I encountered this error about `instagram_prime_archive` collection :

```
SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(),&#8203; indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!

Error closing IndexWriter

null:org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper(NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/solr/data/instagram_prime_archive_shard1_replica_n15/data/index.20190313041339667 lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@6b54ef37; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)): files: [_14jqg.cfe, _14jqg.cfs, _14jqg.si, _14jqg_xcc.liv, _17wrq.cfe, _17wrq.cfs, _17wrq.si, _17wrq_8im.liv, _19qhp.cfe, _19qhp.cfs, _19qhp.si, _19qhp_3ik.liv, _19wns.cfe, _19wns.cfs, _19wns.si, _19wns_1yp.liv, _1a0lx.cfe, _1a0lx.cfs, _1a0lx.si, _1a0lx_9a.liv, _1a3u8.cfe, _1a3u8.cfs, _1a3u8.si, _1a3u8_7g.liv, _1a5fe.cfe, _1a5fe.cfs, _1a5fe.si, _1a5fe_es.liv, _1a7fu.cfe, _1a7fu.cfs, _1a7fu.si, _1a7fu_bg.liv, _1a9oo.cfe, _1a9oo.cfs, _1a9oo.si, _1a9oo_cv.liv, _1abp0.cfe, _1abp0.cfs, _1abp0.si, _1abp0_3fk.liv, _1afn9.cfe, _1afn9.cfs, _1afn9.si, _1afn9_98.liv, _1ajhu.cfe, _1ajhu.cfs, _1ajhu.si, _1ajhu_6r.liv, _1an7f.cfe, _1an7f.cfs, _1an7f.si, _1an7f_6t.liv, _1ap2m.cfe, _1ap2m.cfs, _1ap2m.si, _1ap2m_87.liv, _1au5v.cfe, _1au5v.cfs, _1au5v.si, _1au5v_72.liv, _1audy.cfe, _1audy.cfs, _1audy.si, _1audy_m.liv, _1aup4.cfe, _1aup4.cfs, _1aup4.si, _1aup4_m.liv, _1auza.cfe, _1auza.cfs, _1auza.si, _1auza_x.liv, _1avb8.cfe, _1avb8.cfs, _1avb8.si, _1avb8_u.liv, _1avgt.cfe, _1avgt.cfs, _1avgt.si, _1avgt_k.liv, _1avhd.cfe, _1avhd.cfs, _1avhd.si, _1avhd_8c.liv, _1avq1.cfe, _1avq1.cfs, _1avq1.si, _1avq1_13.liv, _1azqq.cfe, _1azqq.cfs, _1azqq.si, _1azqq_4.liv, _1azwu.cfe, _1azwu.cfs, _1azwu.si, _1azwu_1r.liv, _1b08s.cfe, _1b08s.cfs, _1b08s.si, _1b08s_5.liv, _1b0kq.cfe, _1b0kq.cfs, _1b0kq.si, _1b0kq_m.liv, _1b0ni.cfe, _1b0ni.cfs, _1b0ni.si, _1b0qa.cfe, _1b0qa.cfs, _1b0qa.si, _1b0tm.cfe, _1b0tm.cfs, _1b0tm.si, _1b0tm_1.liv, _1b0zh.cfe, _1b0zh.cfs, _1b0zh.si, _1b100.cfe, _1b100.cfs, _1b100.si, _1b10k.cfe, _1b10k.cfs, _1b10k.si, _1b11e.cfe, _1b11e.cfs, _1b11e.si, _1b11p.cfe, _1b11p.cfs, _1b11p.si, _1b11y.cfe, _1b11y.cfs, _1b11y.si, _1b128.cfe, _1b128.cfs, _1b128.si, _1b12s.cfe, _1b12s.cfs, _1b12s.si, _1b132.cfe, _1b132.cfs, _1b132.si, _1b13c.cfe, _1b13c.cfs, _1b13c.si, _1b13d.dii, _1b13d.dim, _1b13d.fdt, _1b13d.fdx, _1b13d.fnm, _1b13d.nvd, _1b13d.nvm, _1b13d.si, _1b13d_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b13d_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b13d_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b13d_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b13d_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b13d_Lucene70_0.dvm, _1b13e.dii, _1b13e.dim, _1b13e.fdt, _1b13e.fdx, _1b13e.fnm, _1b13e.nvd, _1b13e.nvm, _1b13e.si, _1b13e_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b13e_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b13e_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b13e_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b13e_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b13e_Lucene70_0.dvm, _1b13f.dii, _1b13f.dim, _1b13f.fdt, _1b13f.fdx, _1b13f.fnm, _1b13f.nvd, _1b13f.nvm, _1b13f.si, _1b13f_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b13f_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b13f_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b13f_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b13f_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b13f_Lucene70_0.dvm, _1b14j.dii, _1b14j.dim, _1b14j.fdt, _1b14j.fdx, _1b14j.fnm, _1b14j.nvd, _1b14j.nvm, _1b14j.si, _1b14j_2.liv, _1b14j_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b14j_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b14j_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b14j_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b14j_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b14j_Lucene70_0.dvm, _1b14k.dii, _1b14k.dim, _1b14k.fdt, _1b14k.fdx, _1b14k.fnm, _1b14k.nvd, _1b14k.nvm, _1b14k.si, _1b14k_2.liv, _1b14k_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b14k_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b14k_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b14k_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b14k_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b14k_Lucene70_0.dvm, _1b14q.dii, _1b14q.dim, _1b14q.fdt, _1b14q.fdx, _1b14q.fnm, _1b14q.nvd, _1b14q.nvm, _1b14q.si, _1b14q_2.liv, _1b14q_Lucene50_0.doc, _1b14q_Lucene50_0.pos, _1b14q_Lucene50_0.tim, _1b14q_Lucene50_0.tip, _1b14q_Lucene70_0.dvd, _1b14q_Lucene70_0.dvm, _pqyd.cfe, _pqyd.cfs, _pqyd.si, _pqyd_3bhn.liv, _r9bx.cfe, _r9bx.cfs, _r9bx.si, _r9bx_33sj.liv, write.lock]
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:832)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:124)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:97)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:257)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:344)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:284)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:234)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:950)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1168)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:633)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory$SignatureUpdateProcessor.processAdd(SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory.java:193)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:261)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:188)
at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked the `htop` and found that the number of threads was **9897** !!!
[image]

There was also a lot of threads on the `Thread Dump` screen :
[image]

What can be the reason for these Errors? And why has all this thread been created?

Could my code have a problem?

Comment: Is your index stored on a local disk, or is it attached from a different host? The error seems to indicate that the index has disappeared from underneath Solr..

Comment: @MatsLindh All collections are stored on  my 2 nodes  (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2) with 2 replicas

Answer (score 3):

> Follow the steps to resolve issue:

**Step 1:** cd into your solr directory

**Step 2:** then go to your core data index directory

```
cd server/solr/<your-core-name>/data/index/
```

**Step 3:** then remove the lock file that is stopping the process

```
sudo rm write.lock
```

**Step 4:** cd into your solr directory again

**Step 5:** Now restart the solr instance by running following command

```
bin/solr restart
```

**All Done!** Now you can index again without problem

Answer (score 0):

It may be that SOLR is running using Java8 and the Oracle DB driver you are using does not support it (i.e. 'ojdbc10.jar'). Check the Oracle DB driver installed in the "server/lib" path; if SOLR is running with Java8 then you should have 'ojdbc8.jar' installed.